# reactivate the "application" pan

Tags: deployment, wds, mdt

I use MDT to create images and task sequences, and I deploy them using WDS. 
Version : MDT 2013
adk : 10.1.16299.15

I used the `customsettings.ini` to remove a bunch of screens, only keeping the task sequence choice and the name of the computer. It worked like a charm.

Now that everything is configured for the baseline, I wanted to add the screen where you can choose optional apps to install, so I removed the line `SkipApplications=YES` from my `cs.ini`, and added several optional application in MDT. (I also tried to put `SkipApplications=NO`, same behavior explained here under).

I updated my deployment share (optimize and from scratch, same behavior explained here under), and added the new boot image in WDS(not really useful in this case, but I did it anyway)

When I boot from one of my computers, it goes to wds, launch the regular wizard, but doesn't show the application Pane, only the task sequence choice and the computer details choice (computername only, by design)

I'm sure I edit the correct `cs.ini`, because I changed the `SkipFinalSummary=YES` to `SkipFinalSummary=NO` and I received the final summary. Did other tests too, the behavior changes for every settings except `skipapplication=no`

When I analyze the `ZTIGather.log`, it checks every lines from the `cs.ini`, except the `skipapplication=no`, and I don't know why
when I empty completely my `cs.ini`, it proposes everything... except applications!

I don't know what I need to configure to get them.

I tried the solution here but to no avail (replace the `deploywiz_applications.xml` with a new one): 
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1991281-mdt-wizard-applications-pane-is-blank

Here is my cs.ini (modified for domain name, username and password) :

```
[Settings]
Priority=Default
Properties=MyCustomProperty
[Default]
OSInstall=Y
SkipApplications=NO
SkipCapture=YES
SkipAdminPassword=YES
SkipProductKey=YES
SkipComputerBackup=YES
SkipBitLocker=YES
SkipComputerName=NO
SkipComputerBackup=YES
SkipDeploymentType=YES
SkipRoles=YES
DeploymentType=NEWCOMPUTER
SkipDomainMembership=YES
JoinDomain=tbel.be
DomainAdmin=domainadminusername
DomainAdminDomain=domainadmindomain
DomainAdminPassword=qsdf#
MachineObjectOU=OU=WDSTest,OU=Workstations,OU=Devices,DC=qsdf,DC=com
SkipFinalSummary=NO
SkipLocaleSelection=YES
KeyboardLocale=fr-BE
UserLocale=fr-BE
UILanguage=en-US
SkipPackageDisplay=YES
SkipProductKey=YES
SkipSummary=YES
SkipTimeZone=YES
TimeZoneName=Romance Standard Time
TimeZone=105
SkipUserData=YES
FinishAction=REBOOT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, turns out, it was way easier than I anticipated. So easy I didn't even bother to check it before now... three days later!

The problem didn't lie in the `cs.ini` file, but in my Task Sequence.

As I install every application separately depending on the task sequence, I had removed the line `install application` with the option "install multiple application configured via rules or specified via the deployment wizard" selected. Therefore, when the system was launching the wizard, it checked if there were at least one application to install (there was none, since the line `install application` was removed), and went forward without launching the `deploywiz-Applications.vbs`